# How to use Array.Sort method in a Programmer defined partial Array class in c#?

Tags: c#

Hey everyone I was trying to extended an `Array` with a user defined method (`MajorityElementOf`) in context of my Program. so I use the following code :

```
partial class Array{
    public static object MajorityElementOf(int[] arr)
    {
        Array.Sort(arr);
        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

Compiling this is giving an error:

> 'Array' does not contain a definition for 'Sort';

It may be due to the `Sort` method is not defined in this part of `Array`. Can anyone tell me how to use `Array.Sort(arr)` method in this code ?

Comment: Find a better name for this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your `Array` class takes precedence in effect hiding the other class. You can use the full namespace to get around this, for example:

```
System.Array.Sort(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.Array.Sort(arr);
```

The problem is that the user defined Array class hides the one in the System namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have used same name for class (`Array`), which takes precedence over `System.Array` as local context/scope get precedence. Try qualifying with namespace.

```
System.Array.Sort(arr);
```